# Using d3.map() to make a dictionary of D3 selections

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to make a dictionary of D3 selections of SVG elements. In particular, I'm trying to get the bounding box dimensions of a rectangle within an SVG Baseball field, and put that in a D3 map. I tried it out for the pitcher's mound element ID, and it didn't work.

My console gives me:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

```js
d3.xml("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Baseball_diamond_clean.svg").then(function(xml) {
      document.getElementById('svg_container').appendChild(xml.documentElement)

      const dictionary = map()
        .set('Pitcher', select('#rect2801').node().getBoundingClientRect()); //pitcher;

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="svg_container">

  </div>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Before anything else: that fetch is failing, you have a same-domain policy issue here. Is that SVG the same of this? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Baseball_diamond_clean.svg Because this one is working.

Comment: it is the same, but I changed some of the IDs of the SVG elements. For example, in that one #rect2801 is #firstbase in my edited one.

Comment: That's the only issue here. If I use the other link your code works just right (of course, changing that ID to something else). Just fix this cross-domain issue.

Comment: urgh, I changed it and it's still not working. do you think you could set up a fiddle to show me?

Comment: Why don't **you** set up the fiddle and I just have a look?

Comment: hahah. ok i'll try.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vxhkt4nL/1/ I'm still not sure if this bounding box values of the node are in the map. Is there any way to log the value of the map to a console in JS fiddle? I'm just trying to recreate the problem I'm having in my webpack repo.

Comment: Well, it is clearly there: https://jsfiddle.net/v4jv8axr/ Remember that here in the fiddle it should be `d3.map` and `d3.select`.

Comment: sorry, I'm trying to recreate this problem I'm having in my webpack app, which is why I forgot the d3 namespace. Anyway, I added it, but this still doesn't address if the map is being included with these values. It's hard to display a console and use D3 in something like JS fiddle.

Comment: Can't you see the console in my fiddle? The map is clearly there. I don't know how I can help you further.